# Mountain Lion way to QuickLook folders

Tags: macos, finder, quicklook

The freeware Folder.qlgenerator was already broken by Lion.

```
defaults write QLEnableXRayFolders -bool true
```

does not appear to work in ML. Does anyone have a replacement solution? I’m looking at a large file tree, and I’d like some convenient way to remind myself of what is where. Expanding everything in List View would send most of the information off the bottom of the screen.

Comment: defaults write com.apple.finder QLEnableXRayFolders 1

Comment: @Borderline, as I wrote, this does not appear to work in either Lion or Mountain Lion. I'll try again—but do you have it working on one of these systems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right with "Once upon the Time", that feature does not work on Lion. There is currently no known work around.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a code writer but you can try this.

In finder select the Icon view.

In finder click on the view than on the "show status bar"

That will open a slider at the bottom right.

Using the slider you can adjust the size of the icons to fit your screen.

A nice view of all folders, not xray but a good overview.

FYI: I have OSX 10.8.2 and the xray does not wok with it.

Comment: I don't seem to have been clear. Once upon a time, when you did Quick Look on a folder, a list of the _contents_ came up in the QuickView. So you didn't need to click to open the folder for an idea what was in it.

I don't really need the icons bigger in the existing window. I can just get better glasses. :-)

Comment: "Expanding everything in List View would send most of the information off the bottom of the screen." I was trying to help with this issue you mentioned.